# best practise to handle multiple databases with couchDB

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, database, nosql

I have opted for having a database per user in couchdb. (all the database are totally independent and no aggregation is needed between them)
Now my app is growing and i have thousands of databases.

couchDb does not keep more than 100 open db at the same time.
to improve performance, is it better to

1. keep one instance of couchdb and increase the number of open DB
2. launch another couch DB server instance and split users between.

so to sum up, the question is :

if you have independent data DBs, is it better to scale horizontally or vertically ?

Comment: The best scaling approach for this would be to use a cluster of CouchDB Nodes. Hopefully, this feature will be available in the next 2.0 version. So for the moment I would just increase the max max_dbs_open. CouchDB will easily handle thousand of databases.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally vote for horizontal scaling. It comes with less lookup time and some failure diversification. But, as @Alexis Côté stated, nothing beats the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Clustering ist one of the new inbuild features of CouchDB 2.0

- https://blog.couchdb.org/2016/08/08/release-candidates/
- https://blog.couchdb.org/2016/08/17/migrating-to-couchdb-2-0/